Интеграция 1С и Python
Нужно в Python получить данные из БД 1С кроссплатформенно (COM соединение не пойдет). Как это проще всего сделать? И получится ли это дело протестировать на учебной версии?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Гм... Можно через протокол oData, можно сделать в 1С свой web- или http-сервис. Если база серверная, можно лазить в SQL и оттуда забирать. Можно из 1С по расписанию файлы (с нужными) данными на FTP класть (можно почтой куда-то их отправлять).

Какие данные, насколько оперативно нужно их получать, обмен в одну сторону или в обе, нужна ли синхронизация данных? и т.п. и т.д.
